# how to apply filter different filted wise in mysql dynamically

Tags: mysql, sql

```
CREATE TABLE `EventList` (
  `GroupID` int(11) NOT NULL ,

    `eventID` int(11) NOT NULL ,
  `EMPNAME` varchar(20) NOT NULL,
  `EMPAGE` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `SALARY` bigint(20) NOT NULL,
  `ADDRESS` varchar(20) NOT NULL,
  `empaddress` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  `file_data` tinyblob

) 


insert into eventlist(GroupID,eventID,EMPNAME,EMPAGE,SALARY,ADDRESS,empaddress,file_data) value (1,2,"anil",5,556,'del','del','//document')
insert into eventlist(GroupID,eventID,EMPNAME,EMPAGE,SALARY,ADDRESS,empaddress,file_data) value (1,5,"anil",5,556,'del','del','//document')
insert into eventlist(GroupID,eventID,EMPNAME,EMPAGE,SALARY,ADDRESS,empaddress,file_data) value (1,7,"anil",5,556,'del','del','//document')
insert into eventlist(GroupID,eventID,EMPNAME,EMPAGE,SALARY,ADDRESS,empaddress,file_data) value (1,8,"anil",5,556,'del','del','//document')
insert into eventlist(GroupID,eventID,EMPNAME,EMPAGE,SALARY,ADDRESS,empaddress,file_data) value (1,9,"anil",5,556,'del','del','//document')
insert into eventlist(GroupID,eventID,EMPNAME,EMPAGE,SALARY,ADDRESS,empaddress,file_data) value (2,15,"anil",5,556,'del','del','//document')
insert into eventlist(GroupID,eventID,EMPNAME,EMPAGE,SALARY,ADDRESS,empaddress,file_data) value (2,16,"anil",5,556,'del','del','//document')
insert into eventlist(GroupID,eventID,EMPNAME,EMPAGE,SALARY,ADDRESS,empaddress,file_data) value (3,19,"anil",5,556,'del','del','//document')
insert into eventlist(GroupID,eventID,EMPNAME,EMPAGE,SALARY,ADDRESS,empaddress,file_data) value (3,22,"anil",5,556,'del','del','//document')
insert into eventlist(GroupID,eventID,EMPNAME,EMPAGE,SALARY,ADDRESS,empaddress,file_data) value (3,24,"anil",5,556,'del','del','//document')
insert into eventlist(GroupID,eventID,EMPNAME,EMPAGE,SALARY,ADDRESS,empaddress,file_data) value (3,27,"anil",5,556,'del','del','//document')
insert into eventlist(GroupID,eventID,EMPNAME,EMPAGE,SALARY,ADDRESS,empaddress,file_data) value (3,29,"anil",5,556,'del','del','//document')
insert into eventlist(GroupID,eventID,EMPNAME,EMPAGE,SALARY,ADDRESS,empaddress,file_data) value (0,31,"anil",5,556,'del','del','//document')
insert into eventlist(GroupID,eventID,EMPNAME,EMPAGE,SALARY,ADDRESS,empaddress,file_data) value (0,32,"anil",5,556,'del','del','//document')
insert into eventlist(GroupID,eventID,EMPNAME,EMPAGE,SALARY,ADDRESS,empaddress,file_data) value (0,33,"anil",5,556,'del','del','//document')
insert into eventlist(GroupID,eventID,EMPNAME,EMPAGE,SALARY,ADDRESS,empaddress,file_data) value (0,34,"anil",5,556,'del','del','//document')
insert into eventlist(GroupID,eventID,EMPNAME,EMPAGE,SALARY,ADDRESS,empaddress,file_data) value (0,35,"anil",5,556,'del','del','//document')
insert into eventlist(GroupID,eventID,EMPNAME,EMPAGE,SALARY,ADDRESS,empaddress,file_data) value (0,36,"anil",5,556,'del','del','//document')
insert into eventlist(GroupID,eventID,EMPNAME,EMPAGE,SALARY,ADDRESS,empaddress,file_data) value (0,37,"anil",5,556,'del','del','//document')
insert into eventlist(GroupID,eventID,EMPNAME,EMPAGE,SALARY,ADDRESS,empaddress,file_data) value (0,39,"anil",5,556,'del','del','//document')
```

this is table data i am applying this query for fetch only 4 data for each group wise and if record more than 4 then it display is 1 and I am getting this output from this query

```
SELECT a.*, 
  IF((SELECT COUNT(*) FROM eventlist AS c
      WHERE c.GroupID = a.GroupID) > 4, 1, 0) AS ist
FROM eventlist AS a
WHERE  
  (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM eventlist AS b 
  WHERE b.GroupID = a.GroupID and b.eventID >= a.eventID   ) <= 4  





GroupID   eventID    EMPNAME    EMPAGE  SALARY  ADDRESS empaddress ist
    1          2    anil    5    556     del     del      ...      1
    1          5    anil    5    556     del     del      ...      1 
    1          7    anil    5    556     del     del      ...      1  
    1          2    anil    5    556     del     del      ...      1 
    2          15   anil    5    556     del     del      ...      0 
    2          16   anil    5    556     del     del      ...      0 
    3          19   anil    5    556     del     del      ...      1
    3          22   anil    5    556     del     del      ...      1 
    3          24   anil    5    556     del     del      ...      1
    3          29   anil    5    556     del     del      ...      1
    0          31   anil    5    556     del     del      ...      1 
    0          32   anil    5    556     del     del      ...      1 
    0          33   anil    5    556     del     del      ...      1 
    0          34   anil    5    556     del     del      ...      1
```

I want to apply filter using dynamic where clause for this first I am trying to filter event according to Id but I am unable to do this please help me where am doing wrong this query I am trying to implement for

```
SELECT a.*, 
  IF((SELECT COUNT(*) FROM eventlist AS c
      WHERE c.GroupID = a.GroupID) > 4, 1, 0) AS ist
FROM eventlist AS a
WHERE  
  (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM eventlist AS b 
  WHERE b.GroupID = a.GroupID and b.eventID >= a.eventID   ) <= 4  and  find_in_set( a.eventID,"1,2")
```

but I am unable to get data please tell me where am going wrong.Why I am getting blank data while it should give record for that particular eventID record 1,2

Comment: You can use `and  find_in_set( a.eventID,"1,2")` and it works perfectly. Also you can add `AND a.eventID = 1` to the end of your query instead of `find_in_set` but since you do not have any record in your table that have value 1 for `eventID` this will return 0 records. but if you try with `AND a.eventID = 5` you will get only 1 record. But if you need only record that has `eventID = 5` there is no need to have this complicated query, you can use just `SELECT * FROM eventlist WHERE eventID = 5`. This will do the job for you. So you can use any of these solutions which meets your needs...

Answer (score 0):

You need to apply the `where` clause to the subqueries as well:

```
SELECT a.*, 
       ( (SELECT COUNT(*)
          FROM eventlist AS c
          WHERE c.GroupID = a.GroupID AND c.eventID IN (1, 2)
         ) > 4
       ) AS ist
FROM eventlist AS a
WHERE (SELECT COUNT(*)
       FROM eventlist AS b 
       WHERE b.GroupID = a.GroupID AND b.eventID >= a.eventID AND
             b.eventID IN (1, 2)
      ) <= 4 AND
      a.eventID IN (1, 2);
```

I also replaced the `find_in_set()` with `in`.  That is usually the better approach, but you can use `find_in_set()` instead if yo really want.

Comment: But it give only one record while it should give more record for eventid=1

Comment: @MhanazSyed . . . I don't know what you mean.  You are fetching events for groups.

Comment: i am displaying 4 record from  for each group when i search from eventId 1 ,2 then it should display  2 record for eventid 2 and event id 1 but it display only one record for eventid 2